# Using Add Join while iterating feature classes in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I am building a model that will iterate through feature classes, run the check geometry tool on each, and then join the check geometry output table back to the original feature class.  When the model reaches the join stage, it is adding the attributes of the first feature class to each subsequent feature class it iterates through rather than bringing in the attributes of each feature class as it is sent through the model.

For example:
Iterate Feature Class A
    -Join Layer A Attributes to Geometry Error A
Iterate Feature Class B
    -Join Layer A Attributes to Geometry Error B rather than Layer B attributes

Is there a way to clear the whatever Add Join is storing in memory each iteration?
Or am I simply going about this all wrong.  I hope this makes sense.

Here's the model diagram if that helps:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see the right hand end of the screenshot of your model but it sounds like you have not included a [Remove Join (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000066000000) tool:

> Removes a join from a feature layer or table view.

Try adding that and I *suspect* your model may run more like you want it to.